# How to process files in single mapper

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have 3 files each of 50 MB and want to process in a single Mapper whose Blocksize is 256Mb. How to do it? What are the properties I need to concentrate on? if I set the number of reducers to 5 then what would be the output? where it will get stored?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CombineFileInputFormat()` to combine small files into a single `split` and if you wish you can specify `maxSplitSize` in your code.

If a `maxSplitSize` is specified, then blocks on the same node are combined to form a single split. Blocks that are left over are then combined with other blocks in the same rack. If `maxSplitSize` is not specified, then blocks from the same rack are combined in a single split; no attempt is made to create node-local splits. If the `maxSplitSize` is equal to the block size, then this class is similar to the default spliting behaviour in Hadoop: each block is a locally processed split.

**Source:** http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/CombineFileInputFormat.html

As we know `Mapper` is get assigned based on number of `blocks or input split`. If you combine your file into one split, One mapper will get assigned to process your data.

Please refer below useful link to implement it.

http://www.idryman.org/blog/2013/09/22/process-small-files-on-hadoop-using-combinefileinputformat-1/

http://blog.yetitrails.com/2011/04/dealing-with-lots-of-small-files-in.html

http://hadooped.blogspot.in/2013/09/combinefileinputformat-in-java-mapreduce.html